# I don't get up too late to get to school on time. - is it correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is this sentence correct?

**I don't** get up **too** late **to** get to school on time.

Can I use too ... to in negatives?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

The ***too ... to*** construction is not connected to whether the whole sentence is "a negative". You can make this more obvious if you write out the positive form in full, and compare:

> I do get up too late to get to school on time.

with:

> I don't get up too late to get to school on time.

Another way to say it would be:

> I get up early enough to get to school on time.

Comment: Does your example mean the same as mine? You've got downvoted. Why? Can anyone else confirm if my sentence is correct?

Comment: Let's just say *too late to* (or ***not** too late to*) are correct and I have no idea why someone would downvote with no explanation.

Comment: It was my downvote and I'll explain it.. The question specifically asked about using _too ... to_ in **negative** statements. Your supporting example isn't a negative statement. Therefore, your answer to the question essentially boils down to one word – "Absolutely" – with no supporting evidence, and with no comment about how the OP's sentence sounds. (Personally, I don't think the original is ungrammatical, but I do think it sounds a little awkward. It may not be "incorrect", but I think your alternative reads clearer – yet your answer would indicate they are almost identical in quality.)

Comment: I was trying to show that it was readable and meaningful by showing the corresponding positive statement (sorry). I'll try again ...

Comment: I'm asking this question because in the English textbook there is a grammar topic too ... to ... and (not) enough ... to... and is it possible to make sentences with too ... to ... in negative sentences. Is it possible? Can I write "I'm not too fast to win the marathon." ??

Comment: No; you could say (possibly) *I'm not too slow to win the marathon*, but most people would say *I'm fast enough to ...*.

Comment: @J.R. is this enough?

Comment: What about the sentence: "I'm not too lazy to do this exercise" ?? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, "I'm not too lazy to do this exercise" is correct. I like your answer, Will Crawford, although I agree with J.R. that it is a strange construction by user67549, but, nonetheless, I don't think it's ungrammatical, so I've upvoted you!

Comment: The reason it sounds a little odd is that it implies that they *do* get up "late"